# QLPreviewController and RTF Files

Tags: xcode, image, rtf, qlpreviewcontroller

I tried out using Xcode to create an `RTF` document. One of the things I wanted to do was to insert icons used in my app. I created the icons using Inkscape. Curious if it would work, I tried copying/pasting from Inkscape directly to Xcode. All seemed fine, and I finished composing the document. It looked fine in Xcode.

Then I did some reading to learn what was needed to use `QLPreviewController` to view the document. Amazingly, it worked perfectly on the first try, but the document displayed did not contain any of the pasted icon images.

So I went back to the document in Xcode, and the images don't appear there either. It appears my problem is how to create an RTF document with embedded images, not how to use the preview controller. Pasting the images apparently looks like it works but doesn't really. Is there an alternative that does work?

Comment: Until I figure out what's going one, what I've decided to do is to print the `RTF` file to `PDF`, which doesn't lose the images. Then use `QLPreviewController` to display the `PDF` file.